# How does this android code get the activity from ? material-components-android-codelabs

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

material-components-android-codelabs is a git repo of demo code for material components. In the 102-starter branch of this repo, in LoginFragment.kt, there's this bit of code

`(actvity as NavigationHost).navigateTo(ProductGridFragment(),false)`

In the import statements, nothing in there seems to indicate where `activity` comes from and using android studio to find any declaration goes to a function with the signature `public final FragmentActivity getActivity()`. How is `activity` set and brought into the scope of the fragment?

Comment: For those wondering, [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-codelabs/blob/102-complete/kotlin/shrine/app/src/main/java/com/google/codelabs/mdc/kotlin/shrine/LoginFragment.kt) is the fragment OP is talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin allows you to get and set properties directly without calling the method. E.g. instead of calling `getActivity`, you can just use `activity`. So `(actvity as NavigationHost)` actually translates to `(getActivity() as NavigationHost)`

Check the Kotlin reference [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#declaring-properties). Quote from the linked documentation:

> To use a property, simply refer to it by its name

Comment: Thanks! This pattern of usage isn't immediately obvious looking through the documentation of getters and setters. They probably should include this as an example.

Comment: Additionally i was stumped by the fact there wasn't a corresponding `val activity` somewhere in the class

Comment: Doing some further looking, the activity is a private final Activity in the FragmentHostCallback class

Answer (score 1):

`getActivity()` is a method on `Fragment` instances, and Kotlin allows you to access Java-style setters and getters [as though they're properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters):

```
// getters
val newThing = stuff.getThing()
val newThing = stuff.thing

// setters
stuff.setThing(newThing)
stuff.thing = newThing

// boolean setters
dog.setGood(true)
dog.isGood = true

// boolean getters
val goodBoy = dog.isGood()
val goodBoy = dog.isGood
```

note that the property versions look the same whether you're getting or setting, you're just reading and writing to a single "property". Under the hood, it's making the call to the relevant function.

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment` has a function: `final public FragmentActivity getActivity()`

-> since you're in the scope of a `fragment`, and the function is in the `fragment` scope, too, you don't need any import

To be able to use this activity reference, your fragment needs to be attached to an activity. => This should happen somewhere around `onAttatch()`.

Last tip: when you're in a lifecycle where you're sure you have a backing activity, you can use `requireActivity()` to avoid unnecessary null-checks